# Installing SSIS Feature Pack for Azure for SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

The Azure Data Lake Store Destination is a component of the SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) Feature Pack for Azure for SQL Server 2016.

I have installed the feature Pack, but the Azure Data Lake Store Destination and Source task are not visible in Visual Studio. I have Blob, HDInsight and SQL DW tasks listed under Azure.

I have also tried install´it on another machine - same result. Any clues ?

/Paul S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Data Lake store source and destination are both data flow components, they should be visible if you have switched over to the "Data Flow" view.